# Browser resize tool vs display resolution

Tags: html, browser, resolution, display

So my problem is, with the browser tools i resize to 1600 x 900 and the website is looking good but if i change in windows 10 my display resolution and go see the website (without the browser tools) is looking bad.

So my question is which of these two is the right?

P.S: My monitor is 1920 x 1080 in case is needed.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that your webpage/website is not responsive, so i would suggest you to use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** instead of **%** or **px** because it will make your webpage/website responsive and it will work on all resolutions.

Comment: The problem is, i want to make it responsive but i can't see if is good in a specific resolution because i don't know whitch of the forms is the right.

Comment: @Kingu39 For making it responsive use **Viewport Units**, then you don't have to worry about different resolutions.

Comment: @Kingu39 Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the delay, yes my problem was solved using vw or % but what i do now is instead of using the browser responsive tool i manuality change the resolution on my computer because i found do be more trustworthy.

Comment: @Kingu39 I am so happy that I solved your issue and thanks for accepting and upvoting  my answer it means a lot to me. I hope to get more chances to help you.